# unable to connect bluetooth device in ios 8 even existing code not finding bluetooth and main thing it woring very fine on ios 7

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

problem to connect Bluetooth device like wristband  in ios 8 even existing code not finding Bluetooth and main thing it working very fine on ios 7..my code is as 
suggest me any idea or changes in ios 8 for Bluetooth..

```
-(void)connecttodevice { 
     // Scan for all available CoreBluetooth LE devices 
     NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:info_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:info_UUID_service],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BAND_SERVICE_INFO]]; 
     NSLog(@"device connting....."); 
     CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil]; 
     [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil]; 
     self.centralManager = centralManager; 
 }
```

Comment: -(void)connecttodevice
{
    // Scan for all available CoreBluetooth LE devices
 NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:info_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:info_UUID_service],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BAND_SERVICE_INFO]];
    NSLog(@"device connting.....");
 CBCentralManager *centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
 [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];
    
 self.centralManager = centralManager;
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you are invoking scanForPeripheralsWithServices immediately after creating the CBCentralManager rather than waiting until the central manager is in the powered on state as indicated in the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` delegate.

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central

     if (central.state == CBCentrallManagerStatePoweredOn {
        NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:info_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:info_UUID_service],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BAND_SERVICE_INFO]]; 
        NSLog(@"device connting....."); 
        [central scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:nil];
     }
}
```

in iOS 7 starting the scan before the power on state was indicated issued a warning on the console.  In iOS 8 it doesn't start the scan.