# CBCentralManager is not powered on

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-device-discovery

```
_manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10]; // waiting for centralManagerDidUpdateState invocation
[_manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[ _serviceUUID ] options:nil]; // warning here

...

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    NSLog(@"CBCentralManager state is %i", (int)central.state);
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"Found peripheral: %@", peripheral);
    ...
}
```

For some reason delegate centralManagerDidUpdateState is never invoked and i'm getting warning:

> 2015-04-04 12:59:20.850 xctest[30276:303] CoreBluetooth[WARNING]
>    is not powered on

while starting discovering for peripherals. AFAIK it should work on OSX (I'm on MBA 2013 and OSX Maverics and running XCTest). Bluetooth is turned ON and i can run LightBlue app and discover some BLE devices (i'm sure no BLE apps are running while testing my code). So no `didDiscoverPeripheral` is invoked as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to connect bluetooth device in ios 8 even existing code not finding bluetooth and main thing it woring very fine on ios 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074216/unable-to-connect-bluetooth-device-in-ios-8-even-existing-code-not-finding-bluet)

Comment: Testing core bluetooth is tricky. You should plan it carefully. But I'd say you would be much better off testing the CB parts manually because there are way too many error factors that make automated testing unreliable. You should separate the CB interactions in a small module/library/interface and unit test only the interactions with that interface where you can easily substitute any return values and callbacks for any call.

Answer (score 2):

With OS X 10.13.2 the queue argument to CBCentralManager.init() must be non-nil to trigger a callback, e.g. in Swift

```
manager = CBCentralManager(
  delegate: self,
  queue: DispatchQueue(label: "BT_queue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use background thread as `sleepForTimeInterval` blocks main thread and CBCentralManager uses main thread by default:

```
dispatch_queue_t bt_queue = dispatch_queue_create("BT_queue", 0);
_manager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:bt_queue];
```

So `centralManagerDidUpdateState:` is invoked almost immediately and peripheral is discovered with `didDiscoverPeripheral:`.

Comment: It's good to use a separate queue for Core Bluetooth but don't `sleep`. Core Bluetooth is more or less built up exclusively of asynchronous calls and callbacks. Rely on the callbacks and don't try to time things yourself. Read the corresponding sections of the [Apple CB tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

Comment: Good to have confirmation that separate queue usage is the solution (unlike Palw11 insisted). I've used `sleep` in order to have app logic in one place (instead of lota of callback) just for test. In common case i agree sleeping is not good.